# Why does counter-increment work this way?

Tags: css

Can someone help me understand what's happening with the following? I expect the <li> numbering to match the <h2> numbering, but it doesn't. Why not?

```css
body {
  counter-reset: my-sec-counter;     /* Set "my-sec-counter" to 0 */
  }
.largesection {
  counter-reset: my-sec-counter;
  }
li {
  counter-increment: my-sec-counter;  /* Increment "my-sec-counter" by 1 */  
  }
h2::before {
  content: "Section " counter(my-sec-counter) ". ";
  }
```

```html
<div class="largesection">
  <ol>
    <li><h2>HTML Tutorial</h2></li>
    <li><h2>CSS Tutorial</h2></li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div>
  <ol>
    <li><h2>Bootstrap Tutorial</h2></li>
    <li><h2>SQL Tutorial</h2></li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div class="largesection">
  <ol>
    <li><h2>React Tutorial</h2></li>
    <li><h2>Vue Tutorial</h2></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

I expect the result to be:

```
1. Section 1. HTML Tutorial
2. Section 2. CSS Tutorial
3. Section 3. Bootstrap Tutorial
4. Section 4. SQL Tutorial
1. Section 1. React Tutorial
2. Section 2. Vue Tutorial
```

But instead, it's

```
1. Section 1. HTML Tutorial
2. Section 2. CSS Tutorial
1. Section 3. Bootstrap Tutorial    //The li counter resets here but the h2 counter doesn't
2. Section 4. SQL Tutorial
1. Section 1. React Tutorial
2. Section 2. Vue Tutorial
```

Comment: It doesn't help that either the Chrome implementation or the counters specification is bugged. According to [the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-lists-3/#inheriting-counters), `counter(my-sec-counter)` should display 1,2,1,2,1,2 - as Firefox does. However, that behaviour is pretty counter-intuitive, I wonder if the spec really meant to say what it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. ol counter doesn't use your custom counter.
2. remove the reset in body. It's not necessary and may cause unspecified effects.

See this

```css
.largesection {
    counter-reset: my-sec-counter;
}

ol {
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    /* Increment "my-sec-counter" by 1 */
    counter-increment: my-sec-counter;
}
    
h2::before {     
  content: counter(my-sec-counter) ". Section " counter(my-sec-counter) ". ";
}
```

```html
<div class="largesection">
  <ol>
    <li><h2>HTML Tutorial</h2></li>
    <li><h2>CSS Tutorial</h2></li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div>
  <ol>
    <li><h2>Bootstrap Tutorial</h2></li>
    <li><h2>SQL Tutorial</h2></li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div class="largesection">
  <ol>
    <li><h2>React Tutorial</h2></li>
    <li><h2>Vue Tutorial</h2></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

If you want to use the inner ol counter instead of overriding it, you can use the ol start="3" html attribute on the second ol. This is valid HTML because numbering a list isn't just for styling purposes. In fact, this is the recommended way for screen readers and crawlers.

Comment: I'm trying to make the li counter behave the same way the h2 counter does. I don't want to use ol start=3 for the sake of maintainability. Your answer led me to the correct answer though, so I'm marking it as correct. The way to accomplish my goal is to style the ol {list-style: none;} and li::before {content: counter(my-sec-counter);} Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!